# Passing javascript variable to html textbox

Tags: javascript, html, variables, textbox

i need help on html form.

I got a javascript variable, and I am trying to pass the variable to a html form texbox. I want to display the variable on the textbox dynamically. but i do not know how to pass the variable to the html form and call the variable?

```
var test;

<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="lg" VALUE="" SIZE="25" MAXLENGTH="50" disabled="disabled"><BR><BR>
```

How do i pass test to html form and change its value?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use all-caps HTML.

Answer (score 25):

Pass the variable to the form element like this

your form element

```
<input type="text" id="mytext">
```

javascript

```
var test = "Hello";
document.getElementById("mytext").value = test;//Now you get the js variable inside your form element
```

Comment: thanks. but sorry for not being clear in my previous questions... what if the variable is from another .html file? how do i pass the variable from one html file to another html file?

Comment: @Jonathan Low You really need to provide more detail. because from what you say it sounds like you want to use a cookie or querystring to pass the variable value.  But Im not entirely sure what you are trying to do.  Be more specific in your question.

Comment: i got a html file in which i use javascript to get a variable. 

in the javascript, there is a button, upon pressing, a pop up window will open.. which will trigger another html form with a texbox inside..

i would wan to pass the javascript variable to the html form texbox and display it..

Comment: @Jonathan Low read up on Querystrings.  pass the variable in the URL then get the query string value from `window.location`

Comment: How can you send text to non-`input` element, such as `div`?

Answer (score 4):

```
<form name="input" action="some.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="user" id="mytext">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
  var w = someValue;
document.getElementById("mytext").value = w;

</script>

//php on some.php page

echo $_POST['user'];
```

Answer (score 4):

instead of

```js
document.getElementById("txtBillingGroupName").value = groupName;
```

You can use

```js
$("#txtBillingGroupName").val(groupName);
```

instead of groupName you can pass string value like "Group1"

Answer (score 2):

This was a problem for me, too. One reason for doing this (in my case) was that I needed to convert a client-side event (a javascript variable being modified) to a server-side variable (for that variable to be used in php). Hence populating a form with a javascript variable (eg a sessionStorage key/value) and converting it to a $_POST variable.

```
<form name='formName'>
<input name='inputName'>
</form>

<script>
document.formName.inputName.value=var
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use to localStorage feature of HTML5 to store your *test* value and then access it at any other point in your website by using the `localStorage.getItem()` method.  To see how this works you should look at the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) explanation or the explanation from the [Opera Developer website](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/web-storage/).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```js
document.getElementById("txtBillingGroupName").value = groupName;
```