# how can I print javascript variable in input type textbox value like php echo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

It is possible like php in javascript as below....

```
 <?php
     $var1 = "Hello";
     $var2 = "World";
  ?> 
    <input  type="text" value="<?php echo $var1; ?>" /> 
    <input  type="text" value="<?php echo $var2; ?>" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
       var str = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr";
        var x = str.split(","); 
     </script>
```

I have input `type='text'` in the body tag like

```
 <input id="txtOne" name="txtOne" type="text" value="I want to print here using javascript x[0]" /> 

 <input id="txtOne" name="txtOne" type="text" value="I want to print here using javascript x[1]" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can try like **document.getElementById("txtOne").setAttribute("value",x[0])**

Comment: `$('#txtOne').val(x[0]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing javascript variable to html textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252130/passing-javascript-variable-to-html-textbox)

Comment: there's no way you'll be able you call a js variable inside value="x[0]" in html. you just let the javascript assign it's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create Cookies in page 1 (Create Cookies On this page )
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function createCookie(name,value,days) {
              if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
          }
          else var expires = "";
               document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
          }
   var PartyDetail = $("#firstname").val() +"|"+$("#middlename").val()+"|"+$("#lastname").val();

  createCookie('cookiesPartyDetail',PartyDetail,2);
    </script>

  Now read cookies on second page

 <script type="text/javascript">
      function readCookie(name) {
          var nameEQ = name + "=";
          var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
          for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
               var c = ca[i];
               while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
               if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
             }
            return null;
       }
     window.onload = function()
      {
          var str = readCookie('cookiesPartyDetail');
          //var str = "firstname,middlename,lastname";
          var x = str.split("|");
          for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
          { 
            $(".pending_order_"+[i]).val(x[i]);
          }

      } 

  function delete_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
     }
 </script>

 <input class="pending_order_0" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"  /> 
 <input class="pending_order_1" id="middlename" name="middlename" type="text" />
 <input class="pending_order_2" id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />

 if I want to use again in input type hidden field same like firstname, middlename, lastname my code is here..

 <input class="pending_order_0" id="firstname" name="firstname" type="hidden"  /> 
 <input class="pending_order_1" id="middlename" name="middlename" type="hidden" />
 <input class="pending_order_2" id="lastname" name="lastname" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr";
var x = str.split(",");

var input = document.getElementById("txtOne");
input.value = input.value + x[0];
```

```css
input {
    width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<input id="txtOne" name="txtOne" type="text" value="I wan't print here using javascript " />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any library, you need to work with the DOM.

This is probably what you want.

**See the DEMO** below

```js
var str = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr";
var x = str.split(",");

var input = document.querySelectorAll('.txtOne');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
  input[i].value = x[i];

}
```

```html
<input class="txtOne" name="txtOne" type="text" value="" /> 
<br/>
 <input class="txtOne" name="txtOne" type="text" value="" /> 
<br/>
 <input class="txtOne" name="txtOne" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: can you done with class var input = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');

Comment: Yes. You can do that as well. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Lot Of Thanks Abk

Answer (score -1):

Using **Javascript or one of it's libraries** you can do that.

**Using Jquery:**

```
$("#txtOne").val(x[0]);
```

Comment: I know this but i wan't to print in value="<script>document.write(x[0])</script>" it is possible..

Comment: Note: if jQuery is not tagged, answer based on it will attract downvotes